# How can I change the thickness of individual table borders in Lyx?

Tags: lyx

Let's take the following example:

[image: Example table]

Using Lyx, how can I make the top and the bottom border thicker than the bottom border of the header row?

Comment: This might help? http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/Tables#toc8

Comment: In LaTeX the solution is to load the `booktabs` package, and use `\toprule`, `midrule` and  `bottomrule`. There is also a `\cmidrule` for partial rules. See details in the doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the OP responded to my comment that it was the correct solution to his problem I just repost it as an answer:

> **Formal-style tables using booktabs**
>
> The http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#Professional_tables
>   "`booktabs`" package gives a professional look by not
>   using vertical borders and by adjusting the spacing above and below
>   the horizontal borders. To enable the "`booktabs`" style, right-click
>   the table and select "`Settings`." Under the "`Borders`," tab, in the
>   "`Style`" box, select the "`Formal`" bullet. Hover over the bullet to see
>   a description: "Use the formal (a.k.a. booktabs) border style (no
>   vertical borders)." In addition to not using vertical borders by
>   default, the booktabs style adjusts the horizontal border widths and
>   the spacing to create a professional-looking table.

This description was taken from the [**LyX wiki**](http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/Tables#toc8).